# Postgres | How to extract a value from JSON array that contains multiple JSON objects

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table that holds a column called `additional_info`.
this column contains a JSON object that looks like that:

```
    {
        "dbSources": [{
            "destIp": "10.10.10.29",
            "serviceType": "PostgreSql",
            "srcIp": "10.10.10.68",
            "database": "xe",
            "clusterMember": "",
            "dbId": "PostgreSql_10.10.10.29",
            "clusterName": "",
            "host": "",
            "dbUser": "system",
            "osUser": "",
            "userType": "Unknown",
            "srcApp": ""
        },{
            "destIp": "10.10.10.29",
            "serviceType": "PostgreSql",
            "srcIp": "10.10.10.69",
            "database": "xe1",
            "clusterMember": "",
            "dbId": "PostgreSql_10.10.10.29",
            "clusterName": "",
            "host": "",
            "dbUser": "system",
            "osUser": "",
            "userType": "Unknown",
            "srcApp": ""
        }]
    }
```

I want to extract (to select) the value of "database" where `srcIp` equals `10.10.10.68`.
meaning I want to extract the value "xe" from the first JSON object under the JSON array called `dbSources`.

The only thing that I could do is

```
    select additional_info::json ->'dbSources' as db from table
```

but how can I continue from there?

Comment: Postgres and the version is 12.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
with query as (
select j->>'database' as db,j->>'srcIp' as src_ip from json_array_elements('{
        "dbSources": [{
            "destIp": "10.10.10.29",
            "serviceType": "PostgreSql",
            "srcIp": "10.10.10.68",
            "database": "xe",
            "clusterMember": "",
            "dbId": "PostgreSql_10.10.10.29",
            "clusterName": "",
            "host": "",
            "dbUser": "system",
            "osUser": "",
            "userType": "Unknown",
            "srcApp": ""
        },{
            "destIp": "10.10.10.29",
            "serviceType": "PostgreSql",
            "srcIp": "10.10.10.69",
            "database": "xe1",
            "clusterMember": "",
            "dbId": "PostgreSql_10.10.10.29",
            "clusterName": "",
            "host": "",
            "dbUser": "system",
            "osUser": "",
            "userType": "Unknown",
            "srcApp": ""
        }]
    }'::json->'dbSources') as j)
select db from query where src_ip = '10.10.10.68'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path query:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(additional_info, '$.dbSources[*] ? (@.srcIp == "10.10.10.68").database')
from the_table
```

---

This assumes the column is of type `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `additional_info::jsonb`

Answer (score 1):

For a table with name table_name, this query will extract the value of database whose srcIp is '10.10.10.68'

```
SELECT obj::json#>'{database}' as db_name FROM   edisondb.demo r, json_array_elements(r.some_text::json#>'{dbSources}') obj WHERE  obj->>'srcIp' = '10.10.10.68';
```